# R: Subtract values in one dataframe based on Reference ID in second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have searched hard for an answer and attempted many times to figure out a way to achieve what I am after. I have two XTS dataframes: 1.) Account data 2.) Reference data. Here is some sample data (NOTE: Sample data is not in XTS form but same idea applies):

```
#Accounts Data
df1 <- data.frame(index = c("2015-08-31","2015-07-31","2015-06-30","2015-05-31","2015-04-30","2015-03-31","2015-02-28","2015-01-31","2014-12-31","2014-11-30"),
                  "account1"=runif(10, -5.5,5.5), "account2"=runif(10, -5.5,5.5),"account3"=runif(10, -5.5,5.5))
#Reference Data
df2 <- data.frame(index = c("2015-08-31","2015-07-31","2015-06-30","2015-05-31","2015-04-30","2015-03-31","2015-02-28","2015-01-31","2014-12-31","2014-11-30"),
          "CC456"=runif(10, -5.5,5.5),"EE789"=runif(10, -5.5,5.5),"AA123"=runif(10, -5.5,5.5))
#Accounts and Reference IDs Table
df3 <- data.frame("accounts"=c("account1","account2","account3"),"AccountRef"=c("CC456","EE789","AA123"))
```

so you have df1 (accounts):

```
        index  account1  account2    account3
1  2015-08-31  4.324357  4.313650 -0.94839158
2  2015-07-31 -2.334594 -5.412580 -0.03622573
3  2015-06-30 -3.209001 -3.278428  2.89787864
4  2015-05-31 -4.182272 -1.413639 -3.08145877
5  2015-04-30 -5.169491  1.525406  1.07483264
6  2015-03-31  1.601116 -3.539175  0.50540123
7  2015-02-28  2.843629 -3.127028 -1.56990909
8  2015-01-31 -4.037052 -5.276741  2.14786518
9  2014-12-31  5.165133  2.122590  5.36112955
10 2014-11-30 -0.516639 -5.399451 -3.85471675
```

`df2` contains the data what I need subtract from accounts (with ref IDs as column names):

```
        index      CC456     EE789      AA123
1  2015-08-31  5.4784459  4.804948 -3.2405529
2  2015-07-31  3.3577544 -2.300360 -2.8951527
3  2015-06-30  1.7617227  5.207737 -4.8039332
4  2015-05-31 -5.3399975 -5.431412 -3.9897288
5  2015-04-30  5.3813128  1.123664  1.0381041
6  2015-03-31  4.5766378  3.536293  1.5906431
7  2015-02-28 -0.6529657  4.187261  0.2982024
8  2015-01-31 -3.1963028  4.215060 -3.7630705
9  2014-12-31 -0.7919399  5.022231  0.3401043
10 2014-11-30  0.9654926  2.702521  1.8169502
```

and df3 is the table from which I would identify which column in df2 reference to transform df1 into the difference between df1-df2

The issue is that I have about 200 accounts, and 1200 Ref IDs. **Essentially I want to create a new dataframe which is the result of subtracting each column in df1 by the corresponding refID in df2.**

Comment: Is `df1[as.character(df3$accounts)]-df2[as.character(df3$AccountRef)]` what you are looking for?

Comment: I think this gets me very close. My data seems to be structured in a way different from the sample data I provided. I receive the following error: Error in if (!missing(sec) && sec%%1 != 0) subsec <- 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: Please provide an example as similar as possible to your real dataset. Provide also the expected output. In my comment, I assumed that the `index` column is the same for both datasets (as in your example). If that's not the case, my line won't work.

Comment: The indexes are the same (dates). The issue was with slicing my dfs. When I altered your code a bit, I was able to confirm it was pulling the correct data. However, when I run the whole line (i.e., try to attempt the calculation between DFs), I receive the following error: > accounts4[,acctdetails$Name]-benchmarks4[,acctdetails$Code]
Error in `-.default`(accounts4[, acctdetails$Name], benchmarks4[, acctdetails$Code]) : 
  non-conformable arrays.**My dataframes are XTS, so the date columns would not be subtracted from eachother)

Comment: Yes I enjoy wasting peoples time thats the only reason I'm asking this question at all.. ----  I noticed that with my two dfs, when I preview the first one with head(accounts4) it will only show 5 rows, but when I run head(benchmarks4) it shows 6 rows. Moreover, running each df altogether I receive [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 235 rows ] for accounts4 and [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 232 rows ] for benchmarks4. However, the length of each index is identical (240) and the end date is the same 2015-08-31.

Comment: If you would like better help add to your question `dput(head(benchmarks4)); dput(head(accounts4))`